# How can I prevent Chrome from reopening when it quits?

Tags: google-chrome, web-browser, google, restart, force-quit

When I quit the Google Chrome web browser, it automatically reopens –– it won't stay closed! I tried quitting with Chrome –> Quit Google Chrome and Command-Q. How can I prevent Chrome from reopening when it quits? I searched on Ask Different and Stack Exchange, but I did not find any related questions. Jackson Short asked the question ["Why does my Chrome browser keep restarting"](https://support.google.com/chromebook/thread/15838250/why-does-my-chrome-browser-keep-restarting) on Chromebook Help. But his question refers to a Chromebook, and my question refers to Chrome for Mac.

Comment: [This page](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250282362) at Apple Community may give you a clue. Sounds like browser hijacking to me.

Comment: @IconDaemon Thank you, I will read the thread that you referenced from Apple Community about browser hijacking.